# Create passwords and setup Vault objects/engines on Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am new to K8s and trying to create a Helm chart to setup my application.

I want a frictionless experience for users setting up the application without much manual intervention.

Creating the helm chart i was pleased with the provided templating functionallity but missing one essential thing: Creating passwords.

I don't want the user to have to create the passwords for my API to talk to redis etc.

Setting up Vault is also one of the more difficult parts as its key has to be initially created it then needs to be unlocked and resources like userpass and other engines and resources have to be created.

For a docker-compose setup of the same app i have a "install container" that generates the passwords, creates resources on Vault with its API etc.

Is there another possibility using kubernetes/helm?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Sealed Secrets](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets). It stores secrets encrypted using assimetric keys, so they secrets can be only restored having the proper keys.